# How to set up looging level in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Could you tell me how to set up explicitly logging level in Kibana as INFO?
I have found this but do not know how to use it:

```
logging.silent  
logging.quiet   
logging.verbose     
logging.events
```

Answer (score 0):

As shown in [Kibana's official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/settings.html#settings), by editing your `kibana.yml` or `kibana.yaml`:

```
logging.quiet: true
```

This is for the `quiet` logging, same goes to the other options except `logging.events`.